# Why is Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete deleting the cell instead of the row?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Instead of the entire row being deleted, only cell(i,8) gets deleted. What this code does is, for each cell until the last row, if the cell starts with IM, highlight it, and if a corresponding cell is less than 4, delete the row. Thanks

```
for i = 1 to LastRow Then
    If Left(Cells(i, 1), 2) = "IM" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(140, 220, 100)
        If Cells(i, 8).Value <= 4 Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
next i
```

Comment: You are missing something in your code, the first line has a grammer mistake.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working, I suspect you haven't posted enough info (the `for i = 1 to lastrwo then` is a dead giveaway). I will say one thing though, there should be no need for `EntireRow` since `Rows(i)` is already an entire row. `EntireRow` is what you use if your range is something that *isn't* a row, such as `cells(3,1)`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Rows(i).Delete first but it didn't work either. LastRow seems to work fine in other parts of my code, LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Then I suspect `Rows(i).EntireRow.EntireRow.EntireRow.EntireRow.Delete` will also not work :-)

Comment: Sorry just realised cells(i,8) are not being deleted. But the row is not deleted either and the highlighting on cells(i,1) is being removed. If I remove the delete rows line from my code, the high-lightening on those cells remain.

Comment: As far as I can see, the only way highlighting would be removed by that code is if it does, in fact, delete the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the immediate window. Write these two:

```
rows(5).entirerow.delete
rows(5).delete
```

See that row 5 gets deleted. Your code is wrong, you are probably running something else.

Comment: Thanks but I tried .delete and .entirerow.delete, neither are working. Instead they are just removing the high-lightening on the row.

Comment: Open a new workbook. Write the numbers from 1 to 20 in the first column. Try again.

Comment: Thanks. I tried my code exactly the same way as originally  but instead of deleting the desired row, high-lightening it and that works. Looks like an a problem with the rows(i).delete, anyway the highlighting works just as well.

Comment: Good that you found a way out. Just to let you know once again - your code has a grammer error in the first line, "Then" should be removed.